# convert unicode string to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, type-conversion

I have the Python string `u'\u221220'` aka "−20" with [the Unicode minus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm).

When trying to convert into a float, I'm getting

```py
>>> a = u'\u221220'
>>> float(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\u2212' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string
```

with Python 2 and

```py
>>> a = u'\u221220'
>>> float(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−20'
```

with Python 3.

How can I properly convert `u'\u221220'` into the float `-20.0` in both Python 2 and Python 3? A portable solution would be great.

Comment: Replace all occurrances of the Unicode minus sign with the regular one as a workaround. Further, file a ticket that the parser should be extended. It already has support for more digits than just the plain old `0-9`, so adding support for this minus representation should be possible.

Comment: try `float(a.replace(u'\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-'))` as a workaround. See [related Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10581#msg191011).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If you promote your comment to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it a solution.

Comment: the workaround works for your particular input but I'm hesitant to call it an answer for the *"convert unicode string to float"* question. If it works for you; you could [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @j-f-sebastian:

```py
a = u'\u221220'
float(a.replace(u'\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-'))
```

does the trick. See [the related Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10581#msg191011).